# Move cursor to end of script in Matlab editor

Tags: matlab

When editing a script (on a Macbook Pro) in the Matlab editor, what is a keyboard shortcut to move the cursor to the end of the file?

Comment: I really wonder why the downvote...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command to get to the end of file is

```
Cmd+down arrow
```

But you need to double check in the Preferences->Keyboard->Shortcuts.

Type Cursor End Document in the Search Option. You will see there is a few conflicts. What you can do is customize the shortcut according to yourself.

Comment: I figured it out. On the HOME tab of Matlab, open preferences, then keyboard shortcuts. Under action name, scroll to Cursor End Document; you'll see conflicts below. I unassigned next section in the conflicts. It now works in the editor.

Comment: David your comment should be an answer; It solved my problem. I wonder why these shortcuts are in conflict... It was my default configuration! Thanks